# Raspberry Pi 4./ chromium ignores padding

Tags: html, css, raspberry-pi4

I've been developing a signboard page running on a Raspberry Pi 4, you may see it here (https://www.darlingtonschool.org/signboard).

Only on the RP4 are the padding directives being ignored. Here's an example of the html in question.

```
            <div style="height:15%; background-color:#440579; color:white;padding-top:40px;">
<span style="font-size:4vw; color: white; display:inline;font: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" id="day-span">Day</span>
<span style="font-size:8vw; color: white; display:inline;font: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" id="day-number-span"></span>
```

you can see a screen shot here:
https://www.darlingtonschool.org/media/sizes/aspect640/4594386-4935260.png

If you examine the screen shot, you see the padding over "No Classes" or under "2nd Period" is not being observed.

On the RP4/Chromium there's no padding. On a RP3 / Chromium or anything else I've tried (mac, windows / chrome) padding looks great.

Any ideas?

Comment: The hardware used shouldn't make a difference.  Are you using the same version of Chromium on both?  Use Chromium's inspector to inspect the element and see what is going on.

Comment: Also, why are you writing inline styles?  Keep your styling seperate from your markup by using an external stylesheet.  https://www.hostpapa.com/knowledgebase/understanding-external-internal-inline-css-styles/

Comment: 1. Haven't checked the version. I have inspected the elements and manually  added padding to no salutary effect. 2. I'm using inline styles as a test to see if the style directive were the issue.

Comment: I checked it in Chromium on my PC and it looks fine.  Something is odd about that specific setup with your RPi4.  Maybe try getting a different browser like Firefox on there and try it out.

Comment: so latest version of chromium (74)

Comment: Installed firefox on the RP4. Same issue. As others have stated, you wouldn't think hardware would make a difference, but there it is.

Comment: Are you using the same display/monitor for both pi's?

Comment: Yes, it's a 4K Samsung tv. The RP3 only does 1080p while the RP4 is 4K